# Collapsing count bubble, how to avoid?

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, html

The FB code is loaded in a div hidden on the page.  When a section is clicked, using jQuery I move the content to a new location.  This causes the box_count bubble to collapse, only in IE.  Going into the HTML I see the .connect_widget_number_cloud classed element's width attribute is set to 1px.  Since it's in a different domain I cannot go into the child content and update the width.  Is there anything I can do either: 1. Force the bubble to not show so I can overlay a bubble or 2. Make it render correctly in IE?

The bubble appears as expected until after it's moved.

Answer (score 0):

You could work around this by dynamically adding the widget code instead of putting it inline. You can use an empty placeholder DIV in the appropriate area, then when expanding the section add the code and tell the Javascript SDK to parse it. Example, using jQuery for brevity:

```
var placeholder = $('#placeholder_id');
placeholder.append('<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>');
FB.XFBML.parse(placeholder[0]);
```

One side benefit here is that this means the widget is only rendered when the section is expanding, which might slow down the section's loading marginally but will speed up the rest of the page load.